# SQL statement to get the last row in a table

Tags: php, sql

I have a table - xxxx_nb_lo_update_date -  with a number of columns and rows that are ordered by the variable id. I need to get the last entry in the table, and I've been having trouble with this.the code is not producing any thinng when run .. the content to be displayed is a timestamp ..

```
<?php
   $link = mysql_connect('www.xxxxxxx.co.uk', 'xxxxx', 'axxxxxx');
   if (!$link) {
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
   mysql_select_db("xxxxxxx", $link);

   $numrow122 = mysql_query("SELECT TOP 1 last_lo_update_date FROM xxxx_nb_lo_update_date  ORDER BY id DESC "); 

   echo "<font color='blue'>$numrow122</font>";
   mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: MySQL does not support `TOP n`. That's MS SQL Server syntax.  Instead you want `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: You need to fetch your row from `$numrow122`, which is a result resource, not any kind of value.  `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($numrow122);`

Comment: Thanks,i changed it ,but the output is showing as : Resource id #4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$numrow122 = mysql_query("SELECT last_lo_update_date FROM xxxx_nb_lo_update_date ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"); 

echo "<font color='blue'>" . mysql_result($numrow122, 0, 0) . "</font>";
```

That should get you the exact field you want.

Comment: that's the same, the problem is he is trying to output the resource id

Comment: Thanks,i changed it ,but the output is showing as : Resource id #4

Comment: You can use mysql_result to get just 1 field. With that in mind, the mysql_* functions are deprecated and shouldn't be used at all. But rather than rewrite your whole structure, I'm answering your question as simply as I can.

Answer (score 1):

you should not rely on an autoincremented primary key to establish chronology

that aside, you need to fetch the row

```
$ds = mysql_query("SELECT last_lo_update_date FROM xxxx_nb_lo_update_date ORDER BY id DESC limit 1"); 
$rs = mysql_fetch_array ($rs);

print $rs[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If your id is an AUTO_INCREMENT column can use the function:

```
LAST_INSERT_ID()

SELECT last_lo_update_date FROM xxxx_nb_lo_update_date WHERE yourId = LAST_INSERT_ID()
```